# SharePoint list to show all items, with the exception of closed/completed items that are older than a specific amount of time (e.g. 7 days)?

Tags: filter, custom

I am familiar with filtering the list to only show current items (not closed/completed), but is there a way to show all items ***except any that have been placed in closed/completed status more than 7 days ago***?  I have a column that the user can enter the completed date, so I would be able to calculate based on that.  I am having trouble with the custom filter.  Status ***is not equal to*** Completed does not work, obviously, because that will show everything with the exception of the closed items.

Current relevant columns:

Status (Completed is a choice)
Completed Date

Answer (score 0):

If you don't record the status change date in a separate field with a workflow, you can only rely on filtering by two fields: Status and Modified. View filter lets you filter by Modified less than or equal to [today]-7.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Two `AND` filters, based on three fields.

- Is the task complete more than 7 days ago? `[Today]-7`
- Is the task complete? `Yes`

[image: List Filter Parameters]

The following is the filtered list from more than 7 days ago.
[image: Filtered Completed more than 7 days ago.]

The following is the list with all items.
[image: All list items view]

If you use a user entry field, this all you need to do.
Otherwise, you can have a lot of fun by creating a modified import list, etc., etc.